# Cant write list to txt file for some reason

Tags: python

```
list1= ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

for element in list1:
    file = open("C:\\Users\\chril\\Desktop\\instagram\\Followers.txt", "w")
    file.write(element)
    print(element)
file.close()
```

This code leaves my .txt file only with one line, and its "test3". please help, what am i missing?

Comment: You are opening the file 3 times. Put the `open()` before the loop.

Comment: or use append-mode instead of "w" (overwrite)

Answer (score 2):

Open the file only once and write in it. The easiest way is by using a `with` statement:

```py
list1= ["test1", "test2", "test3"]
with file as open("C:\\Users\\chril\\Desktop\\instagram\\Followers.txt", "w"):
    for element in list1:
        file.write(element)
        print(element)
```

Answer (score 1):

`open(..., 'w')` not only opens the file but also truncates it. You're doing that before each element, so of course only the last appears to be written. At the very least, move the code to open and close the file outside the loop:

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\chril\\Desktop\\instagram\\Followers.txt", "w")
for element in list1:
    file.write(element)
    print(element)
file.close()
```

The more pythonic way to handle file I/O is using a `with` block to manage opening and closing the file, even in case if an error:

```
with open("C:\\Users\\chril\\Desktop\\instagram\\Followers.txt", "w") as file:
    for element in list1:
        file.write(element)
        print(element)
```

Answer (score 0):

Change these lines:

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\chril\\Desktop\\instagram\\Followers.txt", "w")

file.write(element)
```

to these:

```
file = open("C:\\Users\\chril\\Desktop\\instagram\\Followers.txt", "a")
file.write(element + "\n")
```

"w" stands for write, and once you call `write(element)`, it will overwrite all the file's contents.

"a" on the other hand, stands for append and appends to the file. But it does not append a newline automatically, so you need to do it by hand, like I showed you above.

Full code:

```
list1= ["test1", "test2", "test3"]

with open("C:\\Users\\chril\\Desktop\\instagram\\Followers.txt", "a") as file:
        for element in list1:
            file.write(element + "\n")
            print(element)
            file.close()
```

See also: https://thispointer.com/how-to-append-text-or-lines-to-a-file-in-python/

Answer (score 0):

when you open a file by 'open()' with "w" parameter it first wipe out all the thing in the file if file is exists [else it creates an empty file].
As, you here did in every iteration in the for loop you wipe-out file and write a single word and close it. that's why remains last word in the list.
As a remedy open the file and then write word by using `for()` loop after that.
Try to use *python context manager* : `with`.